# How to blink a Red circle over a fail drive slot image base on shell script results?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bash, shell

I am testing 24 HDD and would like to have a Red circle blink to a specific fail slot. See image below.
[HDD Slots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBbgU.png).

I am thinking to add an id to each image source.
My shell test script can provide which slot if it failed by grep log file for failed slots into an array.
But I don't know how to link them and have the Red circle blink right on top of each slot image (multiple drive slots can fail at the same time).

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" media="screen">
</head>

<body>
<h1 class="main">Phy Link Test</h2>

<div class="div1" >
<h2>Front Chassis</h2>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="23.png" alt="17" style="width:100%">
  </div>  
  <div class="column">
    <img src="20.png" alt="14" style="width:100%">
  </div>  
  <div class="column">
    <img src="5.png" alt="5" style="width:100%">
  </div>  
  <div class="column" display: inline>
    <img src="2.png" alt="2" style="width:100%">
    <div class="topfront">top slot</div>
  </div>  
  <div class="column">
    <img src="22.png" alt="16" style="width:100%">
  </div>  
  <div class="column">
    <img src="7.png" alt="7" style="width:100%">    
  </div>  
  <div class="column">
    <img src="4.png" alt="4" style="width:100%">    
  </div>  
  <div class="column">
    <img src="1.png" alt="1" style="width:100%">    
    <div class="middlefront">middle slot</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="21.png" alt="15" style="width:100%">    
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="6.png" alt="6" style="width:100%">    
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="3.png" alt="3" style="width:100%">    
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="0.png" alt="0" style="width:100%">
    <div class="bottomfront">bottom slot</div>  
  </div>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <h2>Back Chassis</h2>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="19.png" alt="13" style="width:100%">
  </div>  
  <div class="column">
    <img src="16.png" alt="10" style="width:100%">
  </div>  
  <div class="column">
    <img src="13.png" alt="d" style="width:100%">
  </div>  
  <div class="column">
    <img src="10.png" alt="a" style="width:100%">
    <div class="topback">top slot</div>
  </div>  
  <div class="column">
    <img src="18.png" alt="12" style="width:100%">
  </div>  
  <div class="column">
    <img src="15.png" alt="f" style="width:100%">    
  </div>  
  <div class="column">
    <img src="12.png" alt="c" style="width:100%">    
  </div>  
  <div class="column">
    <img src="9.png" alt="9" style="width:100%">  
    <div class="middleback">middle slot</div>   
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="17.png" alt="11" style="width:100%">    
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="14.png" alt="e" style="width:100%">    
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="11.png" alt="b" style="width:100%">    
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="8.png" alt="8" style="width:100%">
    <div class="bottomback">bottom slot</div>   
  </div>
  <svg>
    <circle fill="#ff0000" stroke="none" cx="60" cy="60" r="20">
      <animate attributeName="opacity" dur="1s" values="0;1;0" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0.1" />
    </circle>
  </svg>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
body {  
  background-color: lightblue;  
}  

h2,h3 {  
  margin-left: 0px;  
  margin: 0;

}   

.main {
  text-align:center;   
}

.div1 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 5500px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 2px;
}

.topfront {
  position: absolute;
  top: 13%;
  left: 22.5%;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.middlefront {
  position: absolute;
  top: 18.5%;
  left: 22.5%;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.bottomfront {
  position: absolute;
  top: 24%;
  left: 22.5%;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.topback {
  position: absolute;
  top: 33%;
  left: 22.5%;
  font-size: 18px;
}  
.middleback {
  position: absolute;
  top: 38.5%;
  left: 22.5%;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.bottomback {
  position: absolute;
  top: 44%;
  left: 22.5%;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.blinking {
  -webkit-animation: 1s blink ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: 1s blink ease infinite;
  -ms-animation: 1s blink ease infinite;
  -o-animation: 1s blink ease infinite;
  animation: 1s blink ease infinite;
  
}

@keyframes "blink" {
  from, to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes blink {
  from, to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes "blink" {
  from, to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes "blink" {
  from, to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes "blink" {
  from, to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```
<script>
async function findSlot() {
    // read our text file
    try {
        const response = await fetch('./test.txt');
        if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error: ${response.status}`);
        }
    const data = await response.text();
    const failedSlotIds = data.split(/\r?\n/);
    //console.log(failedSlotIds);
    return failedSlotIds;
    }
    catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    }
} 

const slotTest = findSlot();
    console.log(slotTest); //showing promise pending

function setFailed(slotId) {
    const slot = document.getElementById('slot-' + slotId);
    slot.classList.add('failed');
}

for (const slotId of slotTest) setFailed(slotId);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish the red blinking circle with just CSS using the `::after` pseudo element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after

Simplest mechanism is to just add / remove a CSS class, in this case I named the class `failed`. If you have the failed ids ready to go, just add the class by id.

classList API docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

I also simplified the CSS / HTML because I found it a bit hard to work with, you might need to tweak some things with the actual images, since I'm just using the fallback here.

Note that a lot of vendor prefixes aren't necessary in modern browsers:

https://caniuse.com/?search=animation

https://caniuse.com/?search=keyframes

```js
async function getSlotIds() {
  return ['17', '7', '9', 'b'];
}

function setFailed(slotId) {
  const slot = document.getElementById('slot-' + slotId);
  slot.classList.add('failed');
}

getSlotIds().then((slotIds) => { for (const slotId of slotIds) setFailed(slotId); });
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

h2,
h3 {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin: 0;
}

.main {
  text-align: center;
}

.div1 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 5500px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.slot {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 20%;
  height: 60px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.failed::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: 1s blink ease infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
  from,
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="main">Phy Link Test</h2>

<div class="div1" >
<h2>Front Chassis</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="slot" id='slot-17'><img src="23.png" alt="17"></div>
    <div class="slot" id='slot-14'><img src="20.png" alt="14"></div>
    <div class="slot" id='slot-5'><img src="5.png" alt="5"></div>
    <div class="slot" id='slot-2'><img src="2.png" alt="2"></div>
    <div>top slot</div>
  </div>  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="slot" id='slot-16'><img src="22.png" alt="16"></div>
    <div class="slot" id='slot-7'><img src="7.png" alt="7"></div>    
    <div class="slot" id='slot-4'><img src="4.png" alt="4"></div>    
    <div class="slot" id='slot-1'><img src="1.png" alt="1"></div>    
    <div>middle slot</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="slot" id='slot-15'><img src="21.png" alt="15"></div>    
    <div class="slot" id='slot-6'><img src="6.png" alt="6"></div>
    <div class="slot" id='slot-3'><img src="3.png" alt="3"></div>    
    <div class="slot" id='slot-0'><img src="0.png" alt="0"></div>
    <div>bottom slot</div>  
  </div>
  <h2>Back Chassis</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="slot" id='slot-13'><img src="19.png" alt="13"></div>
    <div class="slot" id='slot-10'><img src="16.png" alt="10"></div>
    <div class="slot" id='slot-d'><img src="13.png" alt="d"></div>
    <div class="slot" id='slot-a'><img src="10.png" alt="a"></div>
    <div>top slot</div>
  </div>  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="slot" id='slot-12'><img src="18.png" alt="12"></div>
    <div class="slot" id='slot-f'><img src="15.png" alt="f"></div>    
    <div class="slot" id='slot-c'><img src="12.png" alt="c"></div>    
    <div class="slot" id='slot-9'><img src="9.png" alt="9"></div>  
    <div>middle slot</div>   
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="slot" id='slot-11'><img src="17.png" alt="11"></div>    
    <div class="slot" id='slot-e'><img src="14.png" alt="e"></div>    
    <div class="slot" id='slot-b'><img src="11.png" alt="b"></div>    
    <div class="slot" id='slot-8'><img src="8.png" alt="8"></div>
    <div>bottom slot</div>   
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'll try when I get back home.

Comment: I tried using classList.add with addEventListener "load" but the Red circle is not loading. It only works with "click", "mouseover".

Comment: @user2070544 If you have the ids already, you don't need an event listener. I updated the snippet to simulate that. You need to read your ids then call the function after you have them.

Comment: Can you explain 'slot-' in setFailed() ?

Comment: @user2070544 it's just the arbitrary template I used for `id` in the HTML. For example slot 17 has an id of `slot-17`. You can use whatever you want as long as the JS call matches the HTML - just the id without the prefix is fine.

Comment: I updated the script section in my original post. 
- I verified that I am able to get **failedSlotIds** array **['1 \r', '5 \r', '7 \r', '8 \r', '11'] in findSlot()** 
- The problem I have right now is **slotTest** is showing "Promise pending".
- I can solve that by adding **slotTest.then** but the result will be in another function which **for (const slotId of Object.entries(slotTest)) setFailed(slotId);** will not work.

Comment: I updated data.split and now array return as **['1 ', '5 ', '7 ', '8 ', '11']**

Comment: @user2070544 I've updated the example to show you the syntax.

Comment: I've learned a lot and thank you for your guidance.